# ViewModel Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

I cannot understand why I am getting this error, could you please help me find what I am doing wrong ?

What i am trying to achieve with this ViewModel is because i have many records with the same CartId to use it as a parent and booking.Item.ItemName as a child.

Can you please advise if the way i am trying to do it is correct?

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult MyBookings()
{

    var myBookingList = SystemDB.Carts.Where(s => s.Booking.Login == strLoginName).OrderByDescending(s => s.RecordId).Take(10);


    List<MyBookingsViewModel> result = new List<MyBookingsViewModel>();
    foreach (var item in myBookingList)
    {
        MyBookingsViewModel model = new MyBookingsViewModel();

        model.Carts.RecordId = item.RecordId;
        model.Carts.CartId = item.CartId;
        model.Carts.Booking.Item.ItemName = item.Booking.Item.ItemName;
        model.Carts.Booking.UserFullName = item.Booking.UserFullName;
        model.Carts.Booking.RequestDate = item.Booking.RequestDate;
        model.Carts.StatusCode.StatusCodeName = item.StatusCode.StatusCodeName;
        result.Add(model);
    }


    return View(result);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class MyBookingsViewModel
{
    public Cart Carts { get; set; }
    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}

public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public string CartId { get; set; }       
    public int Count { get; set; }



    [ForeignKey("Booking")]
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Booking Booking { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StatusCode")]
    public int Stage { get; set; }
    public virtual StatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }

    public Cart()
    {
        this.Booking = new List<Booking>();
    }
}

public class Booking
{
     [DisplayName("BookingId")]
    public int BookingId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Item")]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string UserFullName { get; set; }


    [DateStart]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy hh:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DateEnd(DateStartProperty = "StartDate")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy hh:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d MMM yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public System.DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Login")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("NetworkID")]
    public string NetworkID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Comments")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }

}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Carts.RecordId)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action("ItemDetails", new {id=item.Carts.BookingId })" >
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Carts.CartId)
                </a>
            @foreach(var booking in item.Bookings)
   {
     <li>@booking.Item.ItemName</li>
   }
        </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: i get it here : model.Carts.RecordId = item.RecordId;

Comment: `model.Carts` has not been initialised.

Comment: It also appears `result` has not been initialized.

Comment: how about `model.Carts.Booking` and `model.Carts.Booking.Item` and `model.Carts.StatusCode` ?

Comment: I did the change ekad suggested and now although model.cart.recordId is fine i get the same errors at model.carts.booking.item

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at your model class definition

```
public class MyBookingsViewModel
{
    public Cart Carts { get; set; }
    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

and the following lines in your controller code

```
foreach (var item in myBookingList)
{
    MyBookingsViewModel model = new MyBookingsViewModel();

    model.Carts.RecordId = item.RecordId;
    model.Carts.CartId = item.CartId;
    model.Carts.Booking.Item.ItemName = item.Booking.Item.ItemName;
    model.Carts.Booking.UserFullName = item.Booking.UserFullName;
    model.Carts.Booking.RequestDate = item.Booking.RequestDate;
    model.Carts.StatusCode.StatusCodeName = item.StatusCode.StatusCodeName;
    result.Add(model);
}
```

You were trying to set `model.Carts.RecordId` while `model.Carts` is null. You need to initialize `Carts` property before doing so. The initialization should be done in the constructor to avoid code repetition. Change your model class definition to the following

```
public class MyBookingsViewModel
{
    public MyBookingsViewModel()
    {
        this.Carts = new Cart();
    }
    public Cart Carts { get; set; }
    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
As per your comment regarding the error in this line:

```
model.Carts.Booking.Item.ItemName = item.Booking.Item.ItemName;
```

The problem is `model.Carts.Booking` is null when you set the value of `model.Carts.Booking.Item`. This line also has a similar problem:

```
model.Carts.StatusCode.StatusCodeName = item.StatusCode.StatusCodeName;
```

`model.Carts.StatusCode` is null when you set the value of `model.Carts.StatusCode.StatusCodeName`, so you need to add the similar thing to the `Cart` class definition in the constructor like below:

```
public class Cart()
{
    public Cart()
    {
        this.Booking = new Booking();
        this.StatusCode = new StatusCode();
    }
}
```

and also in the `Booking` class definition

```
public class Booking()
{
    public Booking()
    {
        this.Item = new Item();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ekad , that did the trick for Carts but now i am getting the same error 2 lines bellow at : 
model.Carts.Booking.Item.ItemName = item.Booking.Item.ItemName;

Tried to do the same for Bookings but didnt work, any ideas?

Comment: What does the `Cart` class definition look like? I guess the problem is similar.

Comment: What do you mean ? its a simple model class..

Comment: see the updated answer, I think the problem is `model.Carts.Booking` is null when you set `model.Carts.Booking.ItemName = item.Booking.Item.ItemName`

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BookingSystem.Models.Booking>' to 'BookingSystem.Models.Booking'

Comment: i am getting the above error now at the Cart class definition :(

Comment: I think the updated answer will solve your problem. If not, please edit your question and add the class definition of `Cart` and `Booking`.

Comment: Ok done that , i hope it will help you :)

Comment: Please check the latest updated answer, `this.Booking = new List<Booking>();` in the constructor should be changed to `this.Booking = new Booking();`

Comment: Same error at the same place : model.Carts.Booking.Item.ItemName but
Hovering over ".Item." is shown as Null this time instead of the ".Booking."

Comment: It's still the same problem, you have to initialize `model.Carts.Booking.Item` before setting its properties. Same thing with `model.Carts.StatusCode`.